# Generating image from tilelayer WMS with 50% opacity

Tags: leaflet, wms

I'm trying to generate an image with leaflet-headless and leaflet-image with a layer generated by Tilelayer.WMS with an opacity of 0.5

Visually with leaflet everything is half opaque as expected but when generating the image with leaflet-image, the layer is 100% displayed. without any transparency. Am I missing something ?

```
var tileSettings = {
   layers: layerName,
   styles: styleName,
   format: 'image/png',
   transparent: true,
   opacity: 0.5,
   maxZoom: 20,
   maxNativeZoom: 18,
}

var tileLayer = global.window.L.tileLayer.wms(WMS_URL, tileSettings);

layerGroup.addLayer(tileLayer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it needed a pull request -> adding this line of code into function handleTileLayer

```
ctx.globalAlpha = (layer.options && layer.options.opacity) ? layer.options.opacity : 1;
```

Hope it helps